# seleccionar registros coincidentes entre dos tablas mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, busqueda

Quiero obtener los registros coincidentes entre dos tablas mysql

Por un lado, tengo dos tablas relacionadas entre ellas por materiaprimaID, la primera tabla recoge información genérica de la materia prima y la segunda recoge su composición química. Las tablas son las siguientes:

```
**Raw_matrial**
materiaprimaID (int)
codigo (int)
producto (varchat)

**composicion**
compuesto (varchat)
entryNumber (int)
retention_time (int)
porcentaje (int)
materiaprimaID (int)
```

y un ejemplo de materia prima es el siguiente:

```
Código | Producto | Compuesto          | retention_time | entryNumber | porcentaje
6829   | hedione  | Hedione 1          | 32.16          | 55          | 0.039
6829   | hedione  | Hedione  minor 4   | 32.24          | 1499        | 0.415
6829   | hedione  | Hedione  minor 3   | 34.21          | 1498        | 0.38
6829   | hedione  | Hedione 1          | 35.15          | 55          | 87.11
6829   | hedione  | Hedione 2          | 35.35          | 56          | 10.206
6829   | hedione  | Hedione  minor 1   | 35.82          | 1497        | 0.589
6829   | hedione  | Hedione  minor 2   | 36.67          | 1497        | 0.917
6829   | hedione  | Super Cepionate    | 37.21          | 2112        | 0.061
6829   | hedione  | Hedione tr         | 39.89          | 2021        | 0.194
```

Y por otro lado, tengo también dos tablas de proyectos relacionadas por projectoID

```
    **Project**
    ID (int)
    numero_proyecto (int)

    **composicionmatch**
    compuestomatch (varchat)
    entryNumbermatch (int)
    retention_timematch (int)
    porcentajematch (int)
    proyectosID (int)
```

Un ejemplo de proyecto es el siguiente:

```
numero_proyecto| compuestomatch    | retention_timematch | entryNumbermatch | porcentajematch
6              | isopropylcinnamte | 32.16               | 407              | 25.699
6              | ethyl cinnamate   | 32.24               | 350              | 0.079
6              | hedione 1         | 34.21               | 55               | 0.015
6              | hedione minor 4   | 35.15               | 1499             | 0.161
6              | Hedione minor 3   | 35.35               | 1498             | 0.147
6              | Hedione 1         | 35.82               | 55               | 33.72
6              | Hedione 2         | 36.67               | 56               | 39.50
6              | Hedione  minor 1  | 37.21               | 1497             | 0.23
6              | Hedione  minor 2  | 37.53               | 1497             | 0.355
6              | Super Cepionate   | 38.72               | 2112             | 0.023
6              | Hedione tr        | 39.89               | 2021             | 0.075
```

una vez definidas las tablas de materia prima y proyectos lo que deseo es obtener los registros coincidentes entre las dos tablas ordenador por tiempo de retención y obtener el siguiente resultado:

```
compuesto         | retention_time | porcentaje_materia_prima  | retention_timematch | porcentajematch
hedione 1         | 34.21          | 0.039                     | 34.21               | 0.015
hedione minor 4   | 35.15          | 0.415                     | 35.15               | 0.161
Hedione minor 3   | 35.35          | 0.38                      | 35.35               | 0.147
Hedione 1         | 35.82          | 87.11                     | 35.82               | 33.716
Hedione 2         | 36.67          | 10.206                    | 36.67               | 39.503 
Hedione  minor 1  | 37.21          | 0.589                     | 37.21               | 0.228
Hedione  minor 2  | 37.53          | 0.917                     | 37.53               | 0.355
Super Cepionate   | 38.72          | 0.061                     | 38.72               | 0.023
Hedione tr        | 39.89          | 0.194                     | 39.89               | 0.075
```

La secuencia que estoy usando es la siguiente:

```
SELECT
composicion.RT AS RT_materia_prima,
composicion.compuesto AS compuesto_materia_prima,
composicion.cas,
composicion.porcentaje AS porcentaje_materia_prima,
composicionmatch.compuesto AS compuesto_match,
composicionmatch.porcentaje AS porcentaje_match,
raw_material.producto,
raw_material.codigo,
composicionmatch.RT,
composicionmatch.projectosID,
composicionmatch.entryNumberMatch,
composicion.entryNumber
FROM
composicion
INNER JOIN raw_material ON raw_material.materiaprimaID = composicion.materiaprimaID ,
composicionmatch
INNER JOIN projectos ON projectos.id = composicionmatch.projectosID
WHERE
raw_material.codigo = 6829 AND
composicion.entryNumber = composicionmatch.entryNumberMatch AND
projectos.id = 6
GROUP BY RT_materia_prima
ORDER BY
RT_materia_prima ASC,
composicionmatch.RT ASC
```

y el resultado obtenido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el porcentajematch no es el esperado.

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos

Comment: ¿Exactamente cuál es el resultado que esperas?¿a que te refieres con que porcentajematch no es el esperado?

Comment: Hola Josue, el resultado esperado esta descrito en la pregunta es el 5º recuadro gris. A lo que me refiero con que el porcentajematch no es el esperado porque no me respeta el porcentaje del "match". Si comparas la imagen con el 5º recuadro gris lo veras. Saludos.

Comment: @RaúlGómez sin el dataset y un breve glosario de términos, ya has comprobado en preguntas anteriores que es complicadísimo que entendamos el problema para poder ayudarte :) Podrías simplificarlo o darme más detalles como anteriormente. No tengo tus datos, si quieres echarle un vistazo, puedes volver a contactar conmigo por LinkedIn

Comment: Hola David, te envío los datos por E-mail. 
¿El E-mail es el mismo que en preguntas anteriores?

Comment: @DavidJP te he enviado un email con lo solicitado. si no te llega dimelo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de bastante vueltas, entiendo que ésta es la consulta que buscas, particularizada al `codigo=6829` y el `project.id=7` (no te olvides de modificar estos `id` en todas las subconsultas):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT compuesto,porcentaje,porcentaje_match,
      RT,RTmatch,RT-RTmatch desfase
      FROM (
        SELECT codigo,
          LOWER(SUBSTR(producto,1,8)) producto,
          compuesto,RT,entryNumber,porcentaje
          FROM raw_material
          JOIN composicion USING(materiaprimaID)
          WHERE codigo=6829
      ) c1 JOIN (
        SELECT id numero_proyecto,
          LOWER(compuesto) compuestomatch,
          RT RTmatch,
          entryNumberMatch entryNumber,
          ROUND(porcentaje,2) porcentaje_match
          FROM projectos
          JOIN composicionmatch
          ON id=projectosID
          WHERE id=7 
      ) c2 USING(entryNumber)  
  ) c3 WHERE ROUND(desfase,1)=ROUND((
    SELECT RT-RTmatch desfase
      FROM (
        SELECT codigo,
          LOWER(SUBSTR(producto,1,8)) producto,
          compuesto,RT,entryNumber,porcentaje
          FROM raw_material
          JOIN composicion USING(materiaprimaID)
          WHERE codigo=6829
      ) c1 JOIN (
        SELECT id numero_proyecto,
          LOWER(compuesto) compuestomatch,
          RT RTmatch,
          entryNumberMatch entryNumber,
          ROUND(porcentaje,2) porcentaje_match
          FROM projectos
          JOIN composicionmatch
          ON id=projectosID
          WHERE id=7 
      ) c2 USING(entryNumber)
      GROUP BY 1
      HAVING COUNT(*)=(
        SELECT MAX(n) FROM (
            SELECT RT-RTmatch desfase,COUNT(*) n
              FROM (
                SELECT codigo,
                  LOWER(SUBSTR(producto,1,8)) producto,
                  compuesto,RT,entryNumber,porcentaje
                  FROM raw_material
                  JOIN composicion USING(materiaprimaID)
                  WHERE codigo=6829
              ) c1 JOIN (
                SELECT id numero_proyecto,
                  LOWER(compuesto) compuestomatch,
                  RT RTmatch,
                  entryNumberMatch entryNumber,
                  ROUND(porcentaje,2) porcentaje_match
                  FROM projectos
                  JOIN composicionmatch
                  ON id=projectosID
                  WHERE id=7 
              ) c2 USING(entryNumber)
              GROUP BY 1  
          ) c4  
      )  
  ),1)
  ORDER BY RTmatch,RT,porcentaje_match DESC;
```

Ha sido necesario combinar las dos subconsultas intermedias a través de `materiaprimaID` y descartar aquellas "trazas" cuya desviación en el tiempo de retención fuera diferente a la moda, con una precisión fijada en el `ROUND(x,1)` del `WHERE` de la consulta principal.

La idea es que ese tiempo de retención varía en función de la degeneración de la columna para todos los registros por igual, lo que permite diferenciar las "trazas" del compuesto principal.

La consulta impresiona bastante porque repite dos veces la consulta original para calcular la moda. En realidad es la tercera parte de lo que parece.

Ampliaré la respuesta con cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es el resultado esperado para el código 6829 :)